# How to adjust the width of the form control in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

[Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJp2Y.png)

The width of the searchbar does not change unless I explicitly set its width but doing this will also affect how it looks when the window size is small.

I tried using a container with only 1 column but the width still does not fill the entire row.

How do I change the width of the searchbar?

NAVIGATION BAR:

```
    <Navbar style={{ position: 'sticky' }} bg="zocalo-blue" variant="dark" expand="lg" fixed="top">
        <Navbar.Brand className="mr-0">
            Test
        </Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" size="sm"/>
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="justify-content-center flex-md-grow-1">
          <SearchBar />
        </Nav>
        <Nav className="ml-auto align-top">
          <CartIcon />
          <User />
        </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

SEARCH BAR:

```
  <Form className="mb-0" inline>
      <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="search-materials">
        <InputGroup>
          <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="searchbar"/>
          <InputGroup.Append>
            <Button variant="zocalo-orange">
              <div>
                <i className="fa fa-search fa-lg"></i>
              </div>
            </Button>
          </InputGroup.Append>
        </InputGroup>
      </Form.Group>
  </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can control the width by giving style in it.

```
<div style={{width:"100%"}}>
<Search/>
</div>
```